# Notation for applying a function recursively.

Tags: notation, recurrence-relations, recursion, upper-lower-bounds

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is monotonically increasing in $x$ such that $x_t = f(x_{t-1})$ where $t$ represents time.

Let $x_t \leq x'_t$, so
$$ f(x_t) \leq f(f(x'_{t-1})) \leq f(f(f(x'_{t-2}))) \leq \cdots$$

Is there a more elegant way to write the expression with inequalities?

Note: I am unsure what tags to add.

Comment: Question: by definition, $x_t=f(x_{t-1})$. By applying $f$ on both sides,  I get $f(x_t)=f(f(x_{t-1}))$. Of course, it is now valid to replace the $=$ by a $\leq$ and thus to derive your inequality. I was just wondering if this is what you really want to do because it looks a bit strange... if so, the IMO most elegant way to write down what you want to write down is $x_{t}\leq f(x_{t-1})\ \forall t\geq 0$. I don't think you need to explicitly state that one can combine these inequalities...

Comment: @NeitherNor Here, $f$ is monotonic in $x$, and I should have e.g., wrote $f(x_t) \leq f(f(x'_{t-1}))$ where $x_t \leq x'_t$. Since I am just asking about notation, I tried to keep the question as simple as possible. Edit: I updated my question based your comment/observation.

Comment: Now it makes way more sense. What about $x_0\leq x_0'\Rightarrow x_t\leq x_t'\forall t\geq 0$? Looks like this is telling the whole story pretty directly. BTW, you might be interested in the papers of Eduardo Sontag on monotone systems theory (he focuses on time continuous systems, though, but the translation to time discrete is straight forward).

Comment: @NeitherNor Do you have any particular paper by Eduardo Sontag that you suggest? Also, I think your suggestion makes perfect sense, but in my paper, I am describing the function $f$, so I need to include $f$ in the expression for clarity. I might just be picky, but I prefer not to begin or end an expression with dots, but rather, the dots are ideally in the middle, but here, I can't find a way to do that...

Comment: What about $x\leq x'\Rightarrow f^t(x)\leq f^t(x')\forall t\geq 0$, with $f^0(x)=x$ and $f^{t+1}=f\circ f^t$? I think this paper of Sontag is a good starting point: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1235373

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f^n(x_{t-n+1}) \le f^{n+1}(x_{t-n}),$$
where the superscript indicates $n$-fold composition.

Comment: Note that for historical (& practical) reasons this notation convention is not applied to trigonometric functions (circular nor hyperbolic) except for the inverse functions, eg $\tan^{-1}$. Logarithms can use this convention for composition, but you're far more likely to see $\log\log x$ than $\log^2 x$. Also note that $f^{(n)}(x)$ denotes the $n$th derivative of $f(x)$.

Comment: I think this is representation is compact, which is nice, but I think the representation is not instantly clear as in the expression I provided as an example. In my example, I do not like ending the expression in dots because I want to include the index of the last term e.g., a $T$ for the final time. This expression does that but lack instant clarity.